# Id of the specific DIV if clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a page with several DIV and each DIV contains a dropdownlist (DDL). I want to get the ID back of the specified DIV where I changed the value of the DDL.

```
function ChangeValueInDropDownList(ddl) {
    var id = $(".divClass").attr("id");
}
```

Comment: Dupe of the search functionality: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+get+id+of+parent+element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function ChangeValueInDropDownList(ddl) {
    var id = $(ddl).closest(".divClass").prop("id");
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. `ddl` should be passed in to the jquery function, not `this`. `this` doesnt exist in `ChangeValueInDropDownList`

Answer (score 2):

If your select onchange event handler is `ChangeValueInDropDownList` like

```
$('select').on('change', ChangeValueInDropDownList);
```

You should try this,

```
function ChangeValueInDropDownList(e) {
    var id = $(this).closest(".divClass").attr("id");
}
```

or if you are calling `ChangeValueInDropDownList` in side of select handler like

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
     var ddl = $(this);
     ChangeValueInDropDownList(ddl);
});
```

then it should like

```
function ChangeValueInDropDownList(ddl) {
    var id = ddl.closest(".divClass").attr("id");
}
```

Comment: In your first example `ddl` should be renamed to `e` as event argument. In your second example, there is no need in `$(ddl)`, since you already pass a jQuery object.

Comment: @VisioN, Yes, I corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

You say "each DIV contains a dropdownlist". So is the DIV the immediate parent of the dropdownlist? If yes, then try this

```
var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
```